# java testTimer to test execution time

Tags: java, timer

I have a function which checks the satiability of a logic expression also it shows the checking time. I put an input example and it shows that it takes about 10000 milliseconds(10 sec) to run but why when I try to remove all the code lines associated with the testTimer it only took less than a second to run the code with the same input?

```
    protected boolean ￼runSat() {
        testTimer.start();
        boolean result = checkSatisfiability();
        testTimer.stop();
￼        options.getLog().print("\nChecking time was ", testTimer.getResultTim                e()," milliseconds");
        testTimer.reset();
        finaliseStatistic();
        if (result) {cGraph.print(options.getLog());}return result;}
```

￼

The original code is available here: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sourceforge.owlapi/jfact/1.0.0/uk/ac/manchester/cs/jfact/kernel/DlSatTester.java

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Are you saying that when you take the above method, and you comment out all usages of testTimer, your code completes in 0.5 seconds (versus 10 seconds "as is")?

Comment: Sounds weird. Just to get an idea what is going on; I would add println System.currentTimeMillis() after each line. Maybe your testTimer contains a lot of stuff, and reset() ... well does a lot of work?

Answer (score 0):

```
protected boolean ￼runSat() {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        boolean result = checkSatisfiability();
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
￼        options.getLog().print("\nChecking time was ", (endTime - startTime)/1000000," milliseconds");
        testTimer.reset();
        finaliseStatistic();
        if (result) {cGraph.print(options.getLog());}return result;}
```

You could try if this is faster (if that was what you were asking)